# Fitting sklearn GridSearchCV model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am trying to solve  a regression problem on [Boston Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/boston-housing) with help of [random forest regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).I was using [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) for selection of best hyperparameters.

**Problem 1**

Should I fit the `GridSearchCV` on some `X_train, y_train` and then get the best parameters.

OR

Should I fit it on `X, y` to get best parameters.(X, y = entire dataset)

**Problem 2**

Say If I fit it on `X, y` and get the best parameters and then build a new model on these best parameters.
Now how should I train this new model on ?

Should I train the new model on `X_train, y_train` or `X, y.`

**Problem 3**

If I train new model on `X,y` then how will I validate the results ?

My code so far

```
   #Dataframes
    feature_cols = ['CRIM','ZN','INDUS','NOX','RM','AGE','DIS','TAX','PTRATIO','B','LSTAT']

    X = boston_data[feature_cols]
    y = boston_data['PRICE']
```

Train Test Split of Data

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 1)
```

Grid Search to get best hyperparameters

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
param_grid = { 
    'n_estimators': [100, 500, 1000, 1500],
    'max_depth' : [4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}

CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=RFReg, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 10)
CV_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)

CV_rfc.best_params_ 
#{'max_depth': 10, 'n_estimators': 100}
```

Train a Model on the max_depth: 10, n_estimators: 100

```
RFReg = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth = 10, n_estimators = 100, random_state = 1)
RFReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = RFReg.predict(X_test)
y_pred_train = RFReg.predict(X_train)
```

RMSE: `2.8139766730629394`

I just want some guidance with what the correct steps would be

Comment: This is a question about *methodology*, and not programming, hence more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (and arguably off-topic here).

Answer (score 3):

In general, to tune the hyperparameters, you should always train your model over `X_train`, and use `X_test` to check the results. You have to tune the parameters based on the results obtained by `X_test`.

You should never tune hyperparameters over the whole dataset because it would defeat the purpose of the test/train split (as you correctly ask in the **Problem 3**).

Comment: But then the hyperparameters obtained will be biased with the samples present in that `X_train` is what I feel

Comment: Rookie_123, you have a valid concern but any model/hyperparams will inherently be biased to the train set. If it were biased on a test set then you technically can't speak of a test set to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

This is a valid concern indeed.

**Problem 1**

The `GridSearchCV` does cross validation indeed to find the proper set of hyperparameters. But you should still have a validation set to make sure that the optimal set of parameters is sound for it (so that gives in the end train, test, validation sets).

**Problem 2**

The `GridSearchCV` already gives you the best estimator, you don't need to train a new one. But actually CV is just to check if the building is sound, you can train then on the full dataset (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-with-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation for a full detailed discussion).

**Problem 3**

What you already validated is the way you trained your model (i.e. you already validated that the hyperparameters you found are sound and the training works as expected for the data you have).

Comment: This is clarification is with respect to your answer for **Problem 1**: When you say `GridsearchCV` does cross validation, its cross validation will be still be limited to `X_train` and `y_train`, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This is clarification is with respect to your answer for **Problem 3**:  So no need to validate the model created on entire dataset with the best parameters obtained by `GridsearchCV` ?

Comment: Of course, CV will be done on the train dataset. Then you can validate the CV (best estimator) on the test dataset.

Comment: And indeed, you can use the whole dataset for the final training, as indicated on the datascience question.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Please let me know if you know an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604668/how-to-perform-gridsearchcv-with-cross-validation-in-python Thank you :)